# DefinitelyTyped: Add new props typing for existing component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

Is there any way to declare new typing for new `props` within `DefinitelyTyped`? I updated `material-ui` with some new `props` in `SelectField` component, but typings in `DefinitelyTyped` are old. Can I extend in some way `SelectField` typing and add new `props` types? Now I have:

```
<SelectField
    multiple={true}
    hintText="Select type"
    value={[...this.state.values]}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    selectionRenderer={this.selectionRenderer}
>
```

And I need to add `multiple?: boolean` and `selectionRenderer: (values: any[]) => string` types. I tried to `declare module 'material-ui/SelectField' {}` but it not works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
declare module "material-ui" {
    interface SelectFieldProps {
        multiple?: boolean;
        selectionRenderer: (values: any[]) => string;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the syntax is a bit sifferent than what you've tried.

---

#### Edit

If `SelectFieldProps` is defined in the `__MaterialUI` namespace, then this should work:

```
declare module "material-ui" {
    namepsace __MaterialUI {
        interface SelectFieldProps {
            multiple?: boolean;
            selectionRenderer: (values: any[]) => string;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this in `typings/SelectFieldProps.d.ts` and still have `error TS2339: Property 'multiple' does not exist on type...`

Comment: What happens if you past my code in the same file in which you're trying to use it?

Comment: No, it's still not working, of course when I add this props in `node_modules/@types/material-ui/index.s.ts` in `interface SelectFieldProps` it works, but I didn't figure out any way to extend existing typing in other place than `node_modules`

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: I've got list of errors like `error TS2694: Namespace '"material-ui".__MaterialUI' has no exported member 'AppBar'.` and with all other components

Comment: Right. The `__MaterialUI` namespace isn't inside the `material-ui` module, it's just in the same file. I'm not sure how augment it in this case. Maybe @RyanCavanaugh can help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution, @Nitzan answer it's ok, but need some improvements. When I checked out `node_modules/@types/material-ui/index.d.ts` I found that `interface SelectFieldProps` is defined in `namespace __MaterialUI` so I have to write like this:

```
declare namespace __MaterialUI {
  interface SelectFieldProps {
    multiple?: boolean;
    selectionRenderer?: (values: any[]) => string;
  }
}
```

It works in `./src/typings/selectfield.d.ts` and doesn't work if I declare it in the same file where I use `<SelectField />` (probably because of `.d.ts` extension)